# Display a specific creative or line item in DFP

Tags: google-dfp

Is it possible to call (display) a specific creative or a specific line item? I see that line items have IDs but I can't figure out how (or if it's even possible) to call them through the the GPT code.

I have 5 advertisers whose banners rotate among the inventory so that part is fine… but then I want to list, on the website's footer, all 5 advertisers' logos. So in my dashboard I am placing a new line item for the logo for each advertiser to be able to track clicks and impressions, and then I want to call each one separately and display all together instead of having them rotate in one ad unit slot.

Thanks.

Comment: The closest solution I have found is convoluted and requires creating a bunch of extra ad units: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/4430844 It works but seems like it will be high maintenance in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to call (display) a specific creative or a specific
>   line item?

It is not possible to call a specific line item by ID. But you can configure a line item key-value targeting ([1](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/188092?hl=en)) and then communicate a targeting when setting up the GPT ad tag ([2](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PassbackSlot_setTargeting)).

```
googletag.pubads().definePassback('/1234567/sports', [468, 60]).
    setTargeting('color', 'red').
    setTargeting('sport', ['rugby', 'rowing']).
    display();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide a solution. I ended up implementing the separate ad unit solution which, given my level of mastery (read: low) of DFP so far, worked as desired.